# Lyx not working with any \cite, or MMD cite

Tags: lyx, citations

I have a slight problem with Lyx and citations that I have not been able to find a solution to anywhere else.

When inserting any citation style, such as the following (notice #1 and #4 are identical, expect that #1 is greyed out as i inserted it manually):

[image]

Lyx outputs #2 #3 #4 as text, and #1 as a working citation, despite it being identical to #4. 
[image]

--

I have tried switching between different bibtex styles (plain, natbib, ect.) under document/settings/bib and I've added \usepackage{cite}, \usepackage{MMD} to my preamble. But to no avail.

Any ideas how to solve this?

FYI, I am running 2.1.2 on a Macbook Pro (Yosemite 10.10.1), and I use Papers3 as my reference manager.

Any input is appreciated!

best,
T

Comment: This question was not answered properly. Still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will self answer this one.

Answer was simple. Type your citation inside a ERT box. Press CTRL-L to insert ERT box. It should look like this:

[image]